# HornetQ java getMessagesAsJSON feature

Tags: java, jboss, hornetq

I would like to have in Java the same facility that listMessagesAsJSON in the jmx-console provides. How could I do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add something it will be just for properties. There's no way to convert the message blob into JSON specific. Unless you use Base64 or something.

There's already listMessages returning String, Object for Java clients. (with just the message properties). Maybe we could do the same on this.

Anyone can probably make it as it's a simple change. We are open for a patch and would help anyone willing to contribute it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would be outside the scope of a messaging provider.  I'd recommend just using the text interfaces, and using a Java JSON library (several are listed at http://json.org) to parse the text into a JSON object tree.

JSON is already quite compact and quick to parse.  However, if this was truly performance-critical, you could instead pass the data as binary serialized objects (using the binary / byte interfaces) - but without a known standard for this, it would be less-than-portable.

Comment: My concern was to get a list of the messages in the respective queue...and I thought the best example of this was that listMessagesAsJSON from the jmx-console.

Comment: Anything provided through JMX, you could access directly through Java by using the managed bean.  For example, HornetQ should provide something similar to Java's ManagementFactory.get*MXBean().